# Segfault while using Strtok() in C

Tags: c, pointers, operating-system, segmentation-fault, strtok

I'm using C to write my own shell and to handle stream redirects (">" and "<") I'm using strtok() to get them and store relevant information to use later in the program.  I'm not sure why I'm getting a segmenation fault when making the first call.  (The code is pretty messy at the moment).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <readline/readline.h>
#include <readline/history.h>

int main (){
    char *command, *mypath, *buffer, *arglist[1024], *pathlist[1024],
        **ap, *carrotfile1, *carrotfile2;
    char* tokenPtr = malloc(1024);
    buffer = malloc(1024);
    carrotfile1 = malloc(1024);
    carrotfile2 = malloc(1024);
    int loop = 1, code = 0, fail = 0;

    while (loop == 1){
        int argnum = 0, pathnum = 0;
        mypath = malloc(1024);
        if(getenv("MYPATH") == NULL)
            strcpy(mypath, "/bin#.");
        else
            strcpy(mypath, getenv("MYPATH"));
        printf("myshell$ ");
        command = readline("");

        if(strcmp(command, "exit") == 0 || strcmp(command, "quit") == 0)
            return 0;

        if(strcmp(command, "") == 0)
            continue;

        /*Tokenizes Command*/
        /*
          Code 1: > is present
          Code 2: < is present
          Code 3: Both Present
        */
        printf("seg?\n");
        tokenPtr = strtok(command, " "); /*Segfaults this line...*/
        printf("tokenPtr: %s", tokenPtr);
        while(tokenPtr != NULL){
            if(strcmp(tokenPtr, ">") == 0){
                if(code == 0)
                    code = 1;
                else if(code == 2)
                    code = 3;
                else{
                    printf("Error: Cannot have multiple equivalent redirects\n");
                    fail = 1;
                }
                tokenPtr = strtok(NULL, " ");
                strcpy(carrotfile1,tokenPtr);
                tokenPtr = strtok(NULL, " ");
                strcpy(arglist[argnum], tokenPtr);
                argnum++;
            }
            else if (strcmp(tokenPtr,"<") == 0){
                if(code == 0)
                    code = 2;
                else if(code == 1)
                    code = 3;
                else{
                    printf("Error: Cannot have multiple equivalent redirects\n");
                    fail = 1;
                }
                tokenPtr = strtok(NULL, " ");
                strcpy(carrotfile2, tokenPtr);
                tokenPtr = strtok(NULL, " ");
                strcpy(arglist[argnum], tokenPtr);
                argnum++;
            }
            else{
                tokenPtr = strtok(NULL, " ");
                strcpy(arglist[argnum], tokenPtr);
                argnum++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that [code samples](http://sscce.org/) should be complete (which the above is) and concise (which it isn't). This benefits everyone involved, though in different ways.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is this homework, self-study, something you want to use yourself or something you hope to release?

Comment: Thanks I'll keep that in mind for next time.  It's part two of an operating systems class problem (first part was to find and run commands with variable amounts of arguments using PATH).  I have the first part and & background process working also, stream redirects are the last part.  Once parsed, I know how to close the file descriptors within the child process for it all to work.  I'll probably post the completed code here for people looking for a nice example (once I refactor it a bit).

Comment: You should also use [`strncpy`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/strncpy.html) or `strlcpy` rather than [`strcpy`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strlcpy), otherwise your code will be vulnerable to buffer overruns.

Comment: It's a fun problem, nice way to become more familiar with C.

Comment: [Schoolwork](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) should be marked as such, so that it's obvious you're not cheating by asking others to do your work (not that you are, you just have to be careful about such things).

Comment: @outis strncpy is awful as it a) doesn't necessarily NUL-terminate the result and b) pointlessly NUl-fills the result. And strlcpy isn't standard C. See recent discussions on SO.

Comment: @Jim: there are other criticisms of [`strlcpy`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strlcpy#Criticism) as well, but either `strncpy` or `strlcpy` is better than naive use of `strcpy`. On the other hand, since fossuser is learning about OS programming, perhaps this is a good opportunity to learn the issues with overruns and truncation, and proper handling of buffers to prevent same.

Comment: @outis Your citation does not support you -- it only says that one should not **deny** that homework is homework. And of course marking homework as homework does nothing to stop cheating since the cheaters **don't** do that.

Comment: @outis I didn't say that strcpy was good, but the claim that strncpy is better is flat wrong. And there's a little cheat in your statement, as you only use the word "naive" in one case. Of course sophisticated and informed use of X is generally better than naive use of Y.

Comment: @outis Yes, this is a good opportunity to learn about that, and a mention of the problem is appropriate. But just saying "strncpy or strlcpy" is not, and that's what I addressed. Now I'm done with this discussion.

Comment: @Jim: The FAQ says: "Admit that the question is homework. [...] Do this by mentioning that it is homework in the question text". That is, explicitly state a question is schoolwork, which is a stronger satement than don't deny homework is homework. I never claimed that marking homework as homework prevents cheating, it just makes it obvious that someone isn't.

Comment: [...] As for `strcpy` vs `strncpy`, the latter may not prevent crashes when a buffer is too small but it will, in most (if not all) instances, prevent an attacker from controlling where execution jumps to, turning a code execution exploit into a DOS attack, which lessens the severity of damage and is therefore better.

Comment: ... If you wish, add "naive" to the use of `strncpy` or `strlcpy`.

Comment: It didn't occur to me to mark it schoolwork because I didn't realize it mattered (since the problem was pretty specific and I provided a large amount of code).  I'll make sure to do this in future questions to protect myself, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When tested under OS X 10.6.5, the specified line didn't segfault. Where it crashed was:

```
strcpy(arglist[argnum], tokenPtr);
```

which is because `arglist` (and `pathlist`) are allocated space, but not any of the strings they point to. Here's an illustration of `arglist` as an array of pointers (uninitialized as your original code, then zero initialized) and an array of arrays.

[image: array of pointers, uninitialized] [image: array of pointers, initialized] [image: array of arrays]

When you're calling `strcpy` on an uninitialized pointer from `arglist`, you're copying to a random memory location (as depicted in the first image).

To resolve this, you should create a list type and functions to operate on lists.

```
typedef struct list {
    ...
} list_t;

// Initialize a new list. Pass NULL to dynamically allocate list structure.
list_t* createList(list_t* list);
// Destroy a list when done with it. You must free the list* if it was
// dynamically allocated.
void discardList(list_t* list);
// return first item in list
void* first(void);
// return last item in list. Could also be called "top"
void* last(void);
// append item to list
void push(void* item);
// remove & return last item
void* pop(void);
// remove & return first item
void* shift(void);
// prepend item to list
void unshift(void* item);
```

If you implement lists as arrays, `createList` would zero out `arglist` using [`memset`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/memset.html). In the original code, you would also have the option of assigning `{0}` to `arglist` when declaring it:

```
char *arglist[1024] = {0};
```

You could alter the API if you only need to store strings in lists (making a `string_list_t` type) and don't need some operations (such as `shift` and `unshift`. With a `string_list_t`, `push` could allocate space for a string, copy the string item and store the copy in the list structure.

Comment: Are you saying that char *arglist[1024] is pointing to unallocated memory?  I'm unsure how I should allocate memory to solve it, I would prefer to allocate enough so it can run  (not necessarily dynamically for each string).  For the path I used strsep instead of strtok and didn't have this issue.

Comment: `arglist` is an array allocated on the stack. `arglist[i]` is unallocated, for any value of `i`. One option would be to declare a `MAX_TOK_SIZE` macro (or `int const`) and `arglist` as `char arglist[MAX_TOK_SIZE][1024]`, though this will waste a fair bit of memory. I'll update my answer with some other possibilities in a little bit.

Comment: `strsep` alone isn't enough to ensure elements of `pathlist` are allocated. Do you mean you are storing the result of `strsep` directly in `pathlist`, rather than copying them?

Comment: I'm a little confused by the distinction and I don't think what I'm trying to do should be that difficult.  For the pathlist I am directly storing the result from strsep.  Here I'm trying to do the same thing, the only difference is I have to check each piece first and determine if it's a ">" or "<". If it is then I'm going to get the next string in the command and save it as the file that is going to be used later.  The arglist should not contain any carrots or filenames.  Just the command and arguments.

Comment: @fossuser: `strsep` and `strtok` return pointers to allocated memory (the pointers point into the string you're tokenizing). When declared as arrays of pointers, the pointers in `arglist` and `pathlist` initially point to random memory locations. Thus you can store a pointer returned from `strsep` or `strtok` in `arglist`, but not copy to a region pointed to by an initial value in `arglist`. In a debugger, take a look at `command`, `arglist[argnum]` and `tokenPtr` right before you call `strcpy`.

Comment: If you declare `arglist` as an array of arrays, then items in `arglist` are allocated; in particular, they are subsections of the memory allocated to `arglist`. (I'll see if I can draw a picture.)

Comment: I got what I was trying to do working with strsep and I'm going to clean it up and post it here as an example others can learn from (since examples online are somewhat limited).  Thanks a lot for all of the information, I learned a lot from this and I appreciate it.

Comment: @fossuser: a correction: to declare `arglist` as an array of arrays, the declaration should be `char arglist[1024][MAX_TOK_SIZE]`